# Formatting a json writer output format surrounded by [ ]

Tags: c#, json

I am pretty new to json, so most of the things I tried are rather brutish.

What I am trying to do is to get code output into a format like

```
"statusEffects" : [
{
"durationData" : {
"duration" : 1,
"ticksOnActivations" : true,
"useActivationsOfTarget" : true,
"ticksOnEndOfRound" : false,
"ticksOnMovements" : false,
"stackLimit" : 1,
"clearedWhenAttacked" : false
}
],
```

Now with my current code I can already replicate most of it (Even though the code is ugly as hell and very much bruteforcing it because I haven't figured out how to serialize objects) 
But I just can't figure out how to get the output wrapped into [ ]

```
writer.WritePropertyName("Statuseffect");
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("DurationData");
writer.WriteStartObject();
writer.WritePropertyName("Duration");
writer.WriteRawValue(WeaponPPCEffectDutationTextBox.Text);
writer.WritePropertyName("ticksOnAcivations");
writer.WriteRawValue("true");
writer.WritePropertyName("useAcivationsOfTarget");
writer.WriteRawValue("true");
writer.WritePropertyName("ticksOnEndOfRound");
writer.WriteRawValue("false");
writer.WritePropertyName("ticksOnMovements");
writer.WriteRawValue("false");
writer.WritePropertyName("stackLimit");
writer.WriteRawValue(WeaponPPCEffectMaxStacksTextbox.Text);
writer.WritePropertyName("clearedWhenAttacked");
writer.WriteRawValue("false");
writer.WriteEndObject();
writer.WriteEndObject();
```

gives me

```
"Statuseffect": {
"DurationData": {
"Duration": 1,
"ticksOnAcivations": true,
"useAcivationsOfTarget": true,
"ticksOnEndOfRound": false,
"ticksOnMovements": false,
"stackLimit": 1,
"clearedWhenAttacked": false
}
```

I've read some topics here, but those were in php and were using an array. Might that be the better way to get at it? To turn that all into a pure indexed array?
Or would it be better to just serialize it?

Comment: Unless this is a learning project the best way would probably be to just use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: Add `writer.WriteStartArray();` on second line and `writer.WriteEndArray();` on second last line.